# How to create uniform horizontal space?

Tags: spacing, lists

I am creating a set of lists that begin with dates and are then followed by a description. Given that the dates have different horizontal lengths, I would like to insert a command that creates a uniform horizontal space after the date so that all of the descriptions align perfectly. For example, using the following code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, letter]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[margin=1.250in]{geometry}
\singlespacing
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\newenvironment{list2}{
  \begin{list}{$\bullet$}{%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0in}
      \setlength{\parsep}{0in} \setlength{\parskip}{0in}
      \setlength{\topsep}{0in} \setlength{\partopsep}{0in} 
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0.35in}}}{\end{list}}

\begin{document}


Example Paper Title
\begin{list2}
\item[] June 2014: Stanford University 
\item[] Dec 2013: Conference
\end{list2}
\end{document}
```

I would like "Stanford University" and "Conference" to align on the same vertical margin. I've got a lot of lists and each has a different horizontal date length, so any ideas on a version of a `\hspace` that can be applied throughout to generate all of the descriptions to the same margin would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{list2}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[list2]{
  nosep,
  before={\let\makelabel=\mymakelabel},
  leftmargin=*,
  labelwidth=6em,
  label={\hspace{6em}},
}
\newcommand{\mymakelabel}[1]{\textbullet\ #1:\hfill}

\begin{document}

\noindent Example Paper Title
\begin{list2}
\item[June 2014] Stanford University
\item[Dec 2013] Conference
\end{list2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks. Is there a way to move the left margin in while preserving the same space structure? (Whenever I adjust the leftmargin, it loses the alignment after the colons).

Comment: @user2154571 `leftmargin=2cm` (or whatever length you prefer)?

Answer (score 2):

A slightly simpler way to do this, also with `enumitem`.

To indent the list, supply a length to `labelindent`, e.g. `labelindent=1em`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{mybullet}{description}{1}
\SetLabelAlign{myleft}{$\bullet$\ #1\hfil}
\setlist[mybullet]{align=myleft,labelwidth=1in,font=\normalfont,nosep}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Some text
\begin{mybullet}
\item[Sept 2004]{Something}
\item[May 1990]{Something}
\item[June 1215]{Magna Carta}
\end{mybullet}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Great, thanks. Is there a way to move the left margin in while preserving the same space structure? (Whenever I adjust the leftmargin, it loses the alignment after the colons).

Comment: @user2154571 You can add `labelindent=1em` (or whatever length you like) to the list definition.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own environment `datelist`, where date is separated by colon after `\item` sequence.

```
\def\dateliststart{\def\item##1:{\par
   \noindent\hbox to2em{\hss$\bullet$\hss}\hbox to6em{##1:\hss}%
   \hangindent=2em \ignorespaces}}
\newenvironment{datelist}{\bgroup\dateliststart}{\par\egroup}

\begin{datelist}
\item June 2014: Stanford University
\item Dec 2013: Conference
\end{datelist}
```